# Import flow issues with partially imported modules

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I am trying to have an imported module be able to access code from the module being run, but am running into an issue where the module is only partially imported. An example of what I mean would be easier to understand. Have two files in the same folder called `a.py` and `b.py`.

In `a.py`:

```py
from importlib import import_module


def do_a_stuff() -> None:
    print("Doing stuff in A...")


MODULE_B = import_module("b")
MODULE_B.do_a_and_b_stuff()
```

In `b.py`:

```py
import a


def do_a_and_b_stuff() -> None:
    a.do_a_stuff()
    print("Doing stuff in B...")
```

What I want to happen is for `a.py` to print

```
Doing stuff in A...
Doing stuff in B...
```

But when I run this code, I get a circular reference error. I understand why this happens, but want to know how I can make this work the way I want it to.

I've tried importing `b` multiple times in one loop, but that doesn't change anything. Also, `b` cannot have a static import as my application must be able to dynamically chose what file to import at runtime based on user input.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module for the first time, regardless of using the `import` statement or the `importlib` methods, it's like executing the top-level code of the module.

This means that when in `b` you import `a` and it imports `b` back, Python will detect a circular reference loop and break.

After a module has been successfully imported, further imports will only fetch a cached version of the module. This means that the following code works

*a.py*

```py
import b

def do_a_something():
    print("a")

b.do_b_something()
```

*b.py*

```py
def do_b_something():
    import a
    a.do_a_something()
    print("b")
```

Generally you shouldn't be importing like this because the import runs on each function call rather than just once when the module is loaded, but it's a workaround that works well for the scenario you described. The initial `import b` will not trigger the `import a`, so you'll get both modules `a` and `b` loaded. Further imports (like the one inside the method) will provide the already loaded version.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually manage import flow through clever use of `__main__` and `if` statements. For this example:

In `a.py`:

```py
from importlib import import_module


def do_a_stuff() -> None:
    print("Doing stuff in A...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MODULE_B = import_module("b")
    MODULE_B.do_a_and_b_stuff()
```

In `b.py`:

```py
import a


def do_a_and_b_stuff() -> None:
    a.do_a_stuff()
    print("Doing stuff in B...")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, a good way to do it is to create a new file within the same directory called `c.py` which contains the following:

```py
import a
```

In this case, run `c.py` instead of `a.py`. The main benefit of this solution is that `b.py` can access dynamic elements of `a.py`.